# Python 3.6 Module cannot be found: Folium

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, pip, folium

I am trying to import folium into a Jupyter notebook I'm working on and I cannot seem to solve the import issues with the Folium library.  Has anyone else solved this problem?

```
!pip install folium
import pandas as pd
import folium
```

Output from the above yields:

```
`ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-a9938c267a0c> in <module>()
      1 get_ipython().system('pip install folium')
      2 import pandas as pd
----> 3 import folium

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folium'`
```

Comment: did you install folium first??

Comment: Yes.  I tried installing outside Jupyter and from within Jupyter.  I also tried installing using a conda install.

Comment: just type `pip install folium` in cmd or terminal

Comment: I used pip install folium and it works without problem.  Then I get the output per my original question above.

Comment: Are you using a virtualenv?

Comment: No, just a notebook from the default environment.

Comment: Very strange.  If you do `import os` then `os.path`, do you get that default environment?

Comment: Try ``pip3 install folium`` or ``easy_install folium``

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the source:

- Choose the sandbox folder of your choice (~/sandbox for example)

  ```
  $ mkdir visualization
  $ cd visualization
  ```
- Clone folium from github:

  ```
  $ git clone https://github.com/python-visualization/folium
  ```
- Run the installation script

  ```
  $ cd folium
  $ python setup.py install
  ```

Answer (score 12):

It is not available via default conda channel. Try using conda-forge channel to install folium as show below:

```
conda install -c conda-forge folium
```

Answer (score 5):

I solved the same  problem by executing following command

```
python3 -m pip install folium
```

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issues as the original problem. I installed successfully from the shell but jupyter would not recognize the module.

What worked for me was (in the jupyter notebook):

```
!pip install folium
```

Comment: In modern Jupyter, this is better as `%pip install folium`. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) about the modern magic install commands that insure installation occurs in the environment backing the kernel underlying the active notebook.

Answer (score 2):

My method was:

```
$ cd C:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site_packages
```

Then

```
git clone https://github.com/python-visualization/folium.git
git clone https://github.com/pallets/jinja.git
```

I imported Folium then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually git-cloned the github repositories for folium and jinja2 into a file and it worked.

Specifically, on my computer, I changed into the right directory from the command line interface with:

```
$ cd C:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site_packages
```

And then typed:

```
git clone https://github.com/python-visualization/folium.git
git clone https://github.com/pallets/jinja.git
```

Then `import folium` (from within python) worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem while installing with pip3 (macOS with python3).

Manually cloning the github repo solved it.

- Move to the package folder of python 3

  ```
  cd /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/
  ```
- Then

  ```
  git clone https://github.com/python-visualization/folium  
  cd folium  
  python setup.py install
  ```

Answer (score 1):

So for Mac OS with Python 3.x, Anaconda doesn't have the library on its installer by default.
You need to clone and manually install 2 two libraries:

1) Navigate to `/Users/<username>/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages`

2)Folium

`git clone https://github.com/python-visualization/folium.git`

`cd folium`

`python setup.py install`

3)Branca (This library is a spinoff from folium, that would host the non-map-specific features, if importing folium without branca the kernel complains about missing module named branca)

`git clone https://github.com/python-visualization/branca.git`

`cd branca`

`python setup.py install`

4)Restart your kernel

5)Import

`import folium`

`import branca`

Answer (score 1):

Running the following code in the terminal fixed it for me.

```
$ conda install folium -c conda-forge
```

Answer (score 0):

Below mentioned command execute in your root working environment.

Solution 1:

```
pip install folium
```

or

```
pip3 install folium
```

Solution 2:

```
conda install branca
conda install folium
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to reinstall jupyter in new conda env. From what I was able to tell, it runs the Jupyter from preexisting environments and that jupyter does not have access to the packages of the new environment

Answer (score 0):

I am using windows 10. I was getting same issue. This is how I fixed it.

Open Command prompt, run as administrator.

type "python" to check if python is installed, if not install python globally.

if python is installed, you will see python prompt, Ctrl+Z to exit and Run :

```
python -m pip install folium
```

Answer (score 0):

For osx-64  v0.4.0 the following code worked for me:

Install `folium` using:

```
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 folium
```

Then verify if the package has been installed

```
import folium
print('Folium installed and imported!')
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in this thread didn't work for me. So my solution was a little bit strange. I am using a PyCharm, and in my project dir I have a requirements.txt file. PyCharm understands that libraties in this file must be installed, and if they are not, it can install by itself. So I just wrote "folium==0.12.1" in this file and PyCharm done all the work. Maybe another IDE also can do it.