# How can we get tooltips and popups to show in Folium

Tags: python, python-3.x, folium

I am trying to get a tooltip and/or a popup to show on a map.  When I zoom in, this is all that I see.

[image]

Here is the code that I am testing.

```
import folium
import requests
from xml.etree import ElementTree
from folium import plugins

m = folium.Map(location=[40.6976701, -74.2598704], zoom_start=10)
m.save('path')
for lat,lon,name,tip in zip(df_final['Latitude(DecDeg)'], df_final['Latitude(DecDeg)'], df_final['Market Description'], df_final['Project Description']):
    folium.Marker(location=[lat,lon], tooltip = tip, popup = name)
m.add_child(cluster)
m
```

I feel like I'm missing a library, or some such thing.  Any idea why this is not working correctly?

Comment: is this code working without error message ? Where do you create `cluster` ? What is in `cluster` Or maybe you should assign Marker to variable and use `m.add_child(marker)` inside `for`-loop

Comment: i check some documents and it seems it has to be `folium.Marker(...).add_to(m)` and you don't have `.add_to(m)`

Answer (score 9):

It seems you forgot to use `.add_to(m)` to add it to map

```
folium.Marker(...).add_to(m)
```

or

```
marker = folium.Marker(...)
marker.add_to(m)
```

---

Minimal working code:

```
import folium
import webbrowser  # open file in webbrowser

m = folium.Map(location=[40.6976701, -74.2598704], zoom_start=10)

marker = folium.Marker(location=[40.6976701, -74.2598704], 
                       tooltip='<b>Stackoverflow</b><br><br>2021.01.01', 
                       popup='<h1>Happy&nbsp;New&nbsp;Year!</h1><br><br>www:&nbsp;<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Stackoverflow.com</a><br><br>date:&nbsp;2021.01.01')
marker.add_to(m)

m.save('map.html')

webbrowser.open('map.html')  # open file in webbrowser
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense.  I made the change that you recommended, re-ran it, and now I get this error message: NameError: name 'cluster' is not defined
I ran this 'pip install cluster'; everything finished off fine.  I re-started the kernel, re-ran the whole process, and again, I got the error: NameError: name 'cluster' is not defined
I'm working in a Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: and what is `cluster`? Why do you use this name ? if it has to be some variable then create it. If it is module then `import` it.

Comment: I asked Google about `cluster` and `folium` and found example which uses code `cluster = folium.FeatureGroup(name='cluster')` but you don't have it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49419357/1832058

Comment: It works fine now.  Thanks for sticking with me on this one!!  Appreciate it!!