# No module named 'folium' even if installed using Spyder

Tags: python, pip, spyder, folium

Sorry if double-posting (i've checked this : [No module named 'folium' after installing via pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59686308/no-module-named-folium-after-installing-via-pip) and others, but didn't find a solution)
I'm using Spyder IDE for a python project. I need to use "folium" module, i installed it in Spyder with "pip install folium" it worked and told me folium was installed etc.
But now, if i try to import folium, i get the error message : "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folium'"

Do you guys have an idea on how to solve this ?

Thanks !

Comment: Problems like yours are usually due to you having more than one Python environment (Python versions + virtual environments) on your system, and you are somehow installing into one environment, but running from another.  I don't know that IDE.  I use PyCharm.  In PyCharm, you can easily have a setup where the two operations target different Python environments

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44617159/python-3-6-module-cannot-be-found-folium hope this helps